# Terraform Dynamic Blocks

Tags: terraform

I'm trying to enable dynamic blocks for a terraform module which deploys an Azure Web Application Firewall. Within the module is:

```
     policy_settings {
     enabled                     = false 
     file_upload_limit_in_mb     = 100 
     max_request_body_size_in_kb = 128 
     mode                        = "Detection" 
     request_body_check          = true 
     }
```

I would like to enable dynamic blocks within the module as thus:

```
 policy_settings {

     enabled {
         dynamic "true" {
             for_each = var.policy_enabled ? [1] : []
             content {}
         }
         dynamic "false" {
            for_each = var.policy_enabled ? [] : [0]
            content {}
            }
        }   

     mode {
         dynamic "Prevention" {
             for_each = var.policy_mode == "Prevention" ? [1] : []
             content {}
         }

         dynamic "Detection" {
             for_each = var.policy_mode == "Detection" ? [1] : []
             content {}
            }
        }

    request_body_check {
        dynamic "true" {
             for_each = var.request_body_check ? [1] : []
             content {}
         }
         dynamic "false" {
            for_each = var.request_body_check ? [] : [0]
            content {}
            }
        }
```

The error I am getting for all of the policy settings:

```
│ Error: Unsupported block type
│
│   on modules/waf_policies/waf_policy.tf line 25, in resource 
"azurerm_web_application_firewall_policy" "example":
│   25:          enabled {
│
│ Blocks of type "enabled" are not expected here. Did you mean to define argument "enabled"? If so, use the equals sign to assign it a value.
```

I have tried adding an equals sign after the `policy_settings` statement and also after the `enabled` `mode` `request_body_check` blocks. No joy. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to achieve. Why use dynamic block on primitive types?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, I don't think you need to use dynamic block because what you want to setup is the variables not the block.

You want to pass the variables to the block and dynamically generated. You should do like this.

```
    policy_settings {

     enabled = var.policy_enabled ? true : false
     mode = var.policy_mode == "Prevention" ? "Prevention" : "Detection"
     request_body_check = var.request_body_check ? true : false
}
```

if you want to dynamically build up the block, then you should consider whether to use it.

example:

```
dynamic "identity" {
    for_each = var.client_id == "" || var.client_secret == "" ? ["identity"] : []
    content {
      type                      = var.identity_type
      user_assigned_identity_id = var.user_assigned_identity_id
    }
  }
```

This means that the block "identity" will be generated once  var.client_id or var.client_secret is empty. And all variables as content.